# Problem with lat/longs of netCDF when plotting in R

Tags: r, arrays, netcdf, r-raster

I am trying to read/plot monthly seafloor temperature data from [a global climate model](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bvdyxkn7d833qug/tob_Omon_MPI-ESM1-2-HR_ssp126_r1i1p1f1_gn_201501-201912.nc?dl=0) in R using the netCDF4 package and have run into an obstacle where the longitude data is not displaying correctly. I have checked the data in Panoply and it plots perfectly there, but when I plot it in R the longitudes are not correct:

[image: Map]

I have tried rotating and transposing the data to no avail, so would greatly appreciate a solution. The code I'm using is below. Thank you.

```
nc_data <- nc_open("tob_Omon_MPI-ESM1-2-HR_ssp126_r1i1p1f1_gn_201501-201912.nc")

# Save the print(nc) dump to a text file
{
  sink('tob_Omon_MPI-ESM1-2-HR_ssp126_r1i1p1f1_gn_201501-201912_metadata.txt')
  print(nc_data)
  sink()
}

lon <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "longitude", verbose = F)
lon[lon > 180] <- lon[lon > 180] - 360
range(lon)
lat <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "latitude", verbose = F)
range(lat)
t <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "time")

tob.array <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "tob") # store the data in a 3-dimensional array
dim(tob.array) 

fillvalue <- ncatt_get(nc_data, "tob", "_FillValue")
fillvalue


tob.array[tob.array == fillvalue$value] <- NA # change NA values to the standard 'NA'

tob.2015 <- tob.array[,,1:12] # subset of 2015 data

# convert 2015 to raster brick
brick_2015 <- brick(tob.2015, xmn=min(lon), xmx=max(lon), ymn=min(lat), ymx=max(lat), crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+ towgs84=0,0,0"))
plot(brick_2015) # inspect 
brick_2015 <- (t(brick_2015)) # transpose 
plot(brick_2015) # inspect
mean.2015 <- calc(brick_2015, mean) # save as one raster object
plot(mean.2015)
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the metadata in the NetCDF file this is a fairly awkward grid to deal with. Solving these problems within R is mostly not worth the effort. My own preference in these cases is to just regrid to a regular latlon grid using Climate Data Operators:

```
cdo remapbil,r360x180 tob_Omon_MPI-ESM1-2-HR_ssp126_r1i1p1f1_gn_201501-201912.nc out.nc
```